# Why is across() not working like it should?

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr, across

I'm trying to understand how to use the `across()` function in order to `replace _if, replace_at`, variations. But I can't see why this code is not working. I've already checked the "colwise" vignette but it didn't help much.

```
hmeq <- read.csv("http://www.creditriskanalytics.net/uploads/1/9/5/1/19511601/hmeq.csv", 
sep = ",", 
header = TRUE)

replace_na_mean <- function(x){
  mean <- mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  x[is.na(x)] <- mean
  return(x)
}

hmeq %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), replace_na_mean)) #1
hmeq %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, replace_na_mean) %>% head() %>% DT::datatable()#2
```

#1 Output is basically the original data frame without any modifications, it's as if the code isn't doing anything.

[image: Output without any changes to original df]

#2 Is working but I'm trying to replace this with `mutate()` and `across()`:

[image: Output I want but using code #1]

Comment: It is working fine `hmeq %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), replace_na_mean)) %>% filter(BAD == 1, LOAN == 1500) %>% pull(MORTDUE)#
[1] 13500.00 73760.82`. Have you assigned the output back to the object

Comment: One suggestion is not to use assign objects with the function name i.e. `mean`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I still have the same issue, I'm about to pull the hair off my head. It should work, but for some reason it's not doing anything.

Comment: Can you check your package version

Comment: dplyr version 1.0.2. Maybe I should be using 1.0.1?

Comment: I tested with `1.0.1`.  That would be the difference.  Can you change the function to `replace_na_mean <- function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: I just tried that function, it's working fine, but the across function apparently isn't recognising it as it should. Same with the previous function definition.

Comment: May be there is a bug in the new version.

Answer (score 0):

The `across` is working fine

```
library(dplyr) # version - 1.0.1
out <- hmeq %>%
       mutate(across(where(is.numeric), replace_na_mean)) 

out %>%
     filter(BAD == 1, LOAN == 1500) %>% 
     pull(MORTDUE)
  #[1] 13500.00 73760.82
```